# I can not use the 'insert all' to insert values into the table

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I can not use the insert all to insert values into the first_name,last_name and phone columns.

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    account_id NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    first_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR2(100),
    phone VARCHAR2(12) ,
    full_name VARCHAR2(51) GENERATED ALWAYS AS( 
            first_name || ' ' || last_name
    ),
    PRIMARY KEY(account_id)
);

INSERT ALL
INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('John','Mobsey','410-555-0197')
INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Ted','Scherbats','410-555-0198')
INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Leeanna','Bowman','410-555-0199')
SELECT* FROM DUAL;
```

This is the error message I get when I try to Run the code:

> ORA-00001: unique constraint (BTMDATABASE.SYS_C0086595925) violated
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

```
1. INSERT ALL
2. INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Trinity','Knox','410-555-0197')
3. INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Mellissa','Porter','410-555-0198')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exactly, you can not. The way you decided to create unique values for the `account_id` column won't work in `insert all` as all rows get the same value which violates the primary key constraint.

Two workarounds:

- don't use `insert all` but separate `insert` statements
- switch to a **sequence** in order to set primary key column's values

And, here's an example (if you need it):

```
SQL> create table accounts
  2    (account_id number primary key,
  3     first_name varchar2(20) not null
  4    );

Table created.

SQL> create sequence seq_acc;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_acc_seq
  2    before insert on accounts
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.account_id := seq_acc.nextval;
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert all
  2    into accounts (first_name) values ('John')
  3    into accounts (first_name) values ('Ted')
  4    into accounts (first_name) values ('Leeanna')
  5  select * from dual;

3 rows created.

SQL> select * from accounts;

ACCOUNT_ID FIRST_NAME
---------- --------------------
         1 John
         2 Ted
         3 Leeanna

SQL>
```

Comment: You're welcome; I added an example, see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement:

```sql
INSERT ALL
INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('John','Mobsey','410-555-0197')
INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Ted','Scherbats','410-555-0198')
INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Leeanna','Bowman','410-555-0199')
SELECT* FROM DUAL;
```

Will try to give all the rows the same `account_id` which will violate your primary key.

Instead, you can use separate `INSERT` statements; or, if you want a single statement/transaction then you can wrap the `INSERT` statements in an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```sql
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('John','Mobsey','410-555-0197');
  INSERT INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Ted','Scherbats','410-555-0198');
  INSERT INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Leeanna','Bowman','410-555-0199');
END;
/
```

or, you can also use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... UNION ALL ...`:

```sql
INSERT INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)
  SELECT 'Trinity', 'Knox',  '410-555-0197' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Mellissa','Porter','410-555-0198' FROM DUAL;
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM accounts;
```

> ```
> ACCOUNT_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL | PHONE        | FULL_NAME      
> ---------: | :--------- | :-------- | :---- | :----------- | :--------------
>          2 | John       | Mobsey    | null  | 410-555-0197 | John Mobsey    
>          3 | Ted        | Scherbats | null  | 410-555-0198 | Ted Scherbats  
>          4 | Leeanna    | Bowman    | null  | 410-555-0199 | Leeanna Bowman 
>          5 | Trinity    | Knox      | null  | 410-555-0197 | Trinity Knox   
>          6 | Mellissa   | Porter    | null  | 410-555-0198 | Mellissa Porter
> ```

*Note: `account_id` of 1 is the failed `INSERT ALL`.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=92886b6a86aa94362bc4f638954424ce)*

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('John','Mobsey','410-555-0197');
INSERT INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Ted','Scherbats','410-555-0198');
INSERT INTO accounts(first_name,last_name,phone)VALUES('Leeanna','Bowman','410-555-0199');
```